# Effeciently Removing Duplicates from a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, performance

I am trying to effeciently remove duplicate rows from relatively large (several hundred MB) CSV files that are not ordered in any meaningful way.  Although I have a technique to do this, it is very brute force and I am certain there is a moe elegant and more effecient way.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: If order is not important, I would just use the good ol' `sort file | uniq` and get on with my life

Comment: @cularis: wouldn't `sort -u file` do the same thing?

Comment: @Mattias cool! didn't know sort has a unique flag.

Comment: If there is a header line involved you could use `sed` to ignore it.  `sed 1d file | sort -u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove duplicates you will have to have some sort of memory that tells you if you have seen a line before. Either by remembering the lines or perhaps a checksum of them (which is *almost* safe...)
Any solution like that will probably have a "brute force" feel to it.

If you could have the lines sorted before processing them, then the task is fairly easy as duplicates would be next to each other.

Comment: Thanks, I wound up actually dumping it into varchars in SQL Server and having SQL return the unique rows.  It was brute force but it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that the rows you obtain from a CSV end up as lists of lists. You then have to decide on what basis you're de-duplicating (i.e., which column) In the example below, it's the first column (`x[0]`)

```
def dedup(seq):
""" De-duplicate a list based on the first member of the sublist
"""
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
return [x for x in seq if
    x[0] not in seen
    and not seen_add(x[0])]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was looking at the uniqueness of the entire line (essentially only the full line compromised a key) and I was looking for uniqueness of the entire string.  Your technique would work great for certain situations, but these files were too large to do this without memory problems on the underpowered machine I am using.